# How to create session in worklight

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I went to through Encrypted Cache in worklight tutorial. but i think it wont much support for my local storage management. I need to maintain user session in my application. Is there is any possible way to do this. Or it can be achieved tro Jquery ???  Follow by this link  [Forum link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=450217)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? On what devices are you planing your application?

Comment: Hii ravidor. im plan to maintain user session. there is two option to follow.. one is html5 session storage and other is worklight cache storage.  Which one is preferrable ? and the target device is iphone and android

Comment: Why do you need a user session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encrypted cache is for data that you need to keep secure. It has an over head and you need a connection to the internet to create it. HTML5 local storage is much simpler.